# Make text clickable: add urls with a loop

Tags: text-properties, buttons

In my `LaTeX` code I have functions that generate hyperlinks in the PDF file. I have, e.g.:

```latex
\newcommand{\arXivid}[1]{\href{https://arxiv.org/abs/#1}{\tt arXiv:#1}}
```

So, in my `LaTeX` code I have strings like `\arXivid{1207.7235}` that points to `https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.7235`.

I'd like to have these strings clickable in the `emacs`' so I tried this function:

```el
(defun my-follow-link () 
  (interactive)
  (require 'button)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (search-forward-regexp "\\\\arXivid{\\([^}]+\\)}" nil t)
      (save-excursion
    (let* ((b (copy-marker (match-beginning 0)))
           (e (copy-marker (match-end 0)))
           (ID (match-string-no-properties 1))
           (URL (concat "https://arxiv.org/abs/" ID))
           )

      (make-button b e 'action (lambda(x) (browse-url URL)))

      ;; (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
      ;;   (define-key map [mouse-2] '(lambda(x) (browse-url URL)))
      ;;   (put-text-property b e 'keymap map))
      )))
    )
  )
```

I get this error message:

```
Symbol’s value as variable is void: URL
```

1. I understand that let-binding the `URL` variable was not a good idea. But I have no idea to fix my code.
2. The `button` seems to respond only to the `RETURN` key, not to mouse click.
3. I tried also to use `text-property` (the commented code) as explained here: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Clickable-Text.html but the code didn't work (I didn't understand it completely).

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your lambda has a reference to the variable 'URL', what you want is the value of 'URL'. One way to do that is with the backquote ` , which is similar to the normal quote, but allows you to evaluate things i.e.

```
(make-button b e 'action `(lambda(x) (browse-url ,URL)))
```

',URL' there is replaced with the value of 'URL'

See [Backquote](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html#Backquote) for a fuller explanation.

Comment: This doesn't explain why it behaves this way, something you'll want to understand at some point.

Comment: I'm not about to cut & paste half the elisp manual ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The exact behavior of the button depends on whether lexical binding was active when creating it or not.  If yes, then the lambda will capture the `URL` variable because it references something outside of its own scope, that way it ensures that if the lambda is called at a later point, it will correctly resolve `URL`.  For this to work, a so-called closure is created.

If lexical binding was not active, Emacs uses dynamic binding instead which basically means that it will defer resolving the `URL` variable for as long as possible.  Calling the lambda may succeed or not, whether it does depends on whether the referenced variable is bound to a value at function call time.  This means that you can do things such as `(let ((URL "http://example.com")) (funcall the-lambda))` and it will work, but calling it in a context without such a binding will fail.  In case you're wondering why anyone would want this kind of behavior, it easily allows overriding all kinds of variables on the fly, therefore allowing a greater level of freedom when hacking on Emacs.

Lexical binding is an opt-in thing, you'll have to enable it explicitly for each buffer you evaluate code in.  Use `M-x add-file-local-variable-prop-line RET lexical-binding RET t RET`, save the buffer to a file, then `M-x revert-buffer`.  From now an all evaluation of code in that buffer will use lexical binding.